# Apply function to an array matching a criterium

Tags: excel, excel-formula

perhaps I'm just unable to formulate the question, but I was unable to find any matches for this, however is there a way you can return an array of all the matching cells matching criteria?

Let's say the following example

```
            1                    2
 |---------------------|------------------|
1|          A          |         B        |   
 |---------------------|------------------|
2|          1          |         2        |
 |---------------------|------------------|
3|          1          |         3        |
 |---------------------|------------------|
4|          1          |        12        |
 |---------------------|------------------|
5|          2          |         8        |
 |---------------------|------------------|
```

Now in `C2`, I need to find a way to find a `MAX` value, out of entire `B` column, for all the cells that have  value `1` in column `A`.

Now this would be a relatively simple array filter in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), however I'm trying to achieve this by somehow using only excel formulas.

AFAIK, all the methods, like `=INDEX()` or `=VLOOKUP()` can only find a single closest (exact) match. **Is there however to return an array of all the matching results**?

I'd presume it would go something like

```
=INDEX($A$2:$B$5; MATCH($A$2; $A$2:$A$5; 0); 1)
```

However once again issue here being, this would stop on the first occurance, rater than go through the entire array.

Probably only thing I can think of is to exhaustively go over each and every number, return in a separate value every occurance (in a matrix) and then add the number, but that seems like way too much of a hassle

*Expected result:*

```
            1                    2
 |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
1|          A          |         B        |         C        |
 |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
2|          1          |         2        |         12       |
 |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
3|          1          |         3        |         12       |
 |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
4|          1          |        12        |         12       |
 |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
5|          2          |         8        |         8        |
 |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: Sounds like you want MAXIFS?

Comment: @BigBen well yeah, that makes it a lot easier if I knew that function existed. Out of curiosity though, how would you go about doing this if there wasn't a dedicated function for this as I'm still curious about how I would apply it in some offcase scenario, where let's say I needed to find... *I don't know*..., longest string out of all the cells in column A that contain a space.

Comment: Probably a SUMPRODUCT approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested this:

```
   =MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,A1)
```

Returns your desired result.

Answer (score 2):

`SUMPRODUCT` + `MAX` works for older excel versions too:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$1:$A$4=A1)*$B$1:$B$4))
```

[image]